# Series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^k}{e^k(k+1)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^k}{e^k(k+1)!}$$ converge?
Mathematica says it converges by comparison test. But I don't see how.

Comment: See [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Comment: You are right. But this is a problem from second semester calculus, so I expect an easier answer.

Comment: This is a not-so-nice second-semester calculus problem, however.  The demonstration is not too simple...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\sqrt{2\pi}k^{k+1/2}e^{-k}\le k!\le k^{k+1/2}e^{-k+1}$,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^k}{e^k(k+1)!}\le \frac{e}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{1.5}}<\infty.
$$
Also (as you noticed in the comments),
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^k}{e^k k!}\ge \frac{1}{e}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{0.5}}=\infty.
$$

Comment: Might be good to mention your use of Stirling's formula. I don't know if your inequalities strictly hold, but certainly with a fudge factor constant they do, which still implies convergence.

Comment: where does one come from?

Comment: You can check here for example (bounds and not approximation): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation

Comment: It may be of interest to note that using $1/k! \ge k^{-k-0.5}e^{k-1}$, we see that $\sum_k k^k/(e^k k!)$ diverges.

Comment: @d.k.o. Do you know where I can find the proof of the inequality? Thanks.

Comment: I found it on p.253 of Stromberg's Introduction to classical real analysis.

Answer (score 1):

This is not offered so much as a demonstration of the convergence of the series, as it is something to perhaps clarify why it requires a fairly sophisticated method to show convergence.  The Ratio Test gives the unhelpful result of 1 .  It also proves rather difficult to find a satisfactory convergent series to compare to $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^k}{e^k \ (k+1)!}$ .  It seems that *both* factors are required in the denominator for the general term to tend to zero as $ \ k \ $ approaches infinity: the omission of either one will unquestionably produce a divergent infinite series:

[image]

In fact, the "complete" factor of $ \ e^k \ $ itself appear to be necessary in the denominator to produce a sequence of terms in the series that tends to zero.  If we consider a sequence of functions $ \ \phi_n \ , \ n \ge 0 \ $ , defined by using the successive partial sums of the Maclaurin series for $ \ e^x \ $ in place of the exponential term, that is,

$$ \ \phi_0 \ = \  \frac{k^k}{(k+1)!} \ \ ,  \ \ \phi_1 \ = \  \frac{k^k}{(1 + k) \ (k+1)!} \ \ , \ \ \phi_2 \ = \  \frac{k^k}{(1 + k + \frac{k^2}{2!}) \ (k+1)!} \ \ , $$

$$ \phi_3 \ = \  \frac{k^k}{(1 + k + \frac{k^2}{2!} + \frac{k^3}{3!}) \ (k+1)!} \ \ , \  \ \ldots $$

we see in the graph below that the sequence only *gradually* converges toward a function which leads to our convergent infinite series.

[image]

This seems then a rather difficult series for which to demonstrate convergence using the techniques discussed in a standard calculus course; more powerful methods appear to be required.